# How to fix these Typescript errors on the window object of my Vue app?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In a component of my Vue 3 app I need to work with some custom properties on the Window, like this:

```
window.ZohoHCAsapSettings = { //<-- ERROR HERE
  ticketsSettings: {
    preFillFields: {
      email: {
        defaultValue: user.value?.email,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But I get a TypeScript error on `ZohoHCAsapSettings`:

```
Property 'ZohoHCAsapSettings' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. ts(2339)
```

So I tried extending the window like so:

```
interface customWindow extends Window {
  ZohoHCAsapSettings?: unknown;
}
declare const window: customWindow; //<-- ERROR HERE
window.ZohoHCAsapSettings = {
  ticketsSettings: {
    preFillFields: {
      email: {
        defaultValue: user.value?.email,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This removes the error on `ZohoHCAsapSettings` but generates another error on `declare` that says:

```
Modifiers cannot appear here. ts(1184)
```

I'm new to TypeScript so not sure what's going on here.

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE if that matters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Buszmen pointed out, the [global `Window` interface should be augmented with the new property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html). Type declarations are usually stored in their own `.d.ts` file (e.g., `src/globals.d.ts` for global variables).

And if you're using a project scaffolded from `npm init vue`, `npm init vite`, or Vue CLI, the key is to specify the `global` namespace:

```js
// src/globals.d.ts
declare global {
  interface Window { ZohoHCAsapSettings?: unknown; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing like this:

```js
interface Window { ZohoHCAsapSettings?: unknown; }
```

Works here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAsAFDJnIBaWAFlgBIDCAggM5wAOAyhGGKAOYsA-AC5kAVxABrELhABuEgF8SJHJlwA6KrUasO3XgJbIAvARJk+CKTxaG+IQWKKly7KBABiwADa+fCF8MFhdLcjIIAFs4PzC3CLIMCHhxXzAANThfcQgxcRZoTQA3bNyhTWjY3wAacIilOoTkRvDW4iV5IA)